# How to get email and username when Facebook registers

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As far as I know, on the new Facebook API, there is no way to get the Facebook username. Also, if the user registered to Facebook, his or her account might lack an email address if he or she logged in with a phone number.

However, I am working on a project, where, upon login with Facebook, if the user does not have a user, then the Facebook login is interpreted as a registration. Since, according to my best knowledge, there is no way to get the Facebook username using the API, I am using the email field to generate a username, taking into account only letters.

However, in some cases, the username generated this way is duplicated, or the Facebook account does not have an email address. The best solution I can think about is to redirect the user to a form where he or she can enter the email and/or the username, but that would not help the user-experience.

Is there a way to gather these data without making the user enter them? Or something close to it?

Comment: "if the user does not have a user"...weird

Comment: @luschn, I have meant that we have a guest user, who is not logged in. This guest user has a Facebook user, which might be linked to an application user or not. In that sentence I was meaning the latter.

Comment: _“Is there a way to gather these data without making the user enter them?”_ – so you know that this is about data that is (username) or might not (email) be available – and yet you are still asking if that can magically appear from out of nowhere somehow …? Letting the user provide the necessary information, if it can not be gathered automatically, _is_ the best option. (As luschn already said, _suggesting_ a username automatically created from available data such as first and last name, is a viable option to reduce friction.)

Comment: "o you know that this is about data that is (username) or might not (email) be available" No, I do not know. I assume. Please, spare me with useless comments about magically getting  unavailable data. If you can confirm that the data is unavailable, or correct my assumption, then you are contributing to this post. If you sarcastically make fun of my question, then you are showing kindergarten level. I do not know of such a way, so I assume that the user will have to enter the missing data. Am I right, or not?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should always present the data you want to store to the user BEFORE you store it, and let him change it.

That being said, the (App Scoped) ID is the only thing that is really unique, you can either use the email directly (if the user is already registered, just add the Facebook ID to your database) and present an input field if there is no email - or generate a username with his first and last name. Present the chosen username to the user and let him change it, or tell him that it already exists.

After all, wouldn´t a user WANT to choose his username?

If you want to make it smooth for the user and don´t want to bug him in anyway, you can just store his Facebook ID. Or just use the email directly as username (including the @ sign and the domain), as i wrote above. If that´s not good enough, you need to implement your own routine to auto-generate usernames. **There´s no general logic from Facebook to do this.**

Comment: The user can set his or her username, but the whole point of registering with Facebook is to have a register feature, which does the job of registration upon a single click. I am talking only about registering with Facebook, since if the person already has an application user, then gathering username and/or password is irrelevant. What if the user does not have an email?

Comment: if you want to make it smooth for the user and don´t want to bug him in anyway, you can just store his facebook id.

Comment: That is a number and it is unintuitive from the user's perspective. I had that as a previous solution, but the client, understandably, did not like it. I would need a username and an email. I am getting both from the email in the way I have described, but in case any of those is already used, or the user registered with phone number to Facebook instead of email, my solution does not work. I can generate magical texts using the name or the facebook id, but that is unintuitive. Thus, the question is given: is there a way to achieve what I want, or something close to it?

Comment: why not use the email directly as username?

Comment: Again: A Facebook account not necessarily has an email address, since users might register to Facebook using their phone numbers, without giving their email address. In this case I cannot get an email from Facebook. "Note, even if you request the email permission it is not guaranteed you will get an email address. For example, if someone signed up for Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email field may be empty." (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-public_profile)

Comment: well, you need a fallback then, to show the user an input field where he can enter his email. not sure what you want to hear, to be honest. you can either use the ID, which is ALWAYS there and always unique, or you need to implement your own routine to generate a username that is not taken, with the information you get from the facebook api (name, for example).

Comment: Friend, I do not need fallback logic. I am asking whether a main logic exists. If not, then I will use a work-around. Facebook's API does not seem helpful with their login system, but please, do not tell me to use Facebook ID for a username/email. It is illogical, to say the least to do so for emails. And it is not user-friendly to do so for username. The best thing I can come up with is to ask for the missing data in a form, as I have already described in my question. I am either right, or wrong. If I am right, there is no sensible solution. If I am wrong, then these fields can be gathered.

Comment: everything that´s possible in my answer. there is no predefined logic for this. facebooks api is actually VERY helpful, the user id is perfect to store a user and usernames are usually decided by the user anyway.